# javascript code for @

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, validation, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to do validate my email address. In order to get this i have been over web and found these Regexs for validating email-

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

Can say there is no limit of regex over internet.

How do you code `@` in javascript code? 
When a user press keys- `shift`+`2`=`@` .

Can we do this?

```
\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+(keycode==64)(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\b
```

I want to write key instead of writing simple `@`

Comment: The question is why would you want to do it? Keycode in REgex would surprise me

Comment: Regex works on the character/string itself. If you want to match `@`, you have to write `@`.
PS: *Why* do you want to do that?

Comment: @winner_joiner: I have cshtml page, when i write @ it counts it as call, so encounters an error.

Comment: You need to escape `@` character like `\@`.

Comment: @Bibhas: No, why? `@` is not a regex metacharacter.

Comment: @TimPietzcker In ASP.NET pages built using the Razor view engine, @ is the tag for starting a Razor code block, which means that Razor will try to parse everything after the @, so when the Javascript gets to it, half the regex will be missing because Razor will have removed it.

Comment: @anaximander: Thanks, that's interesting. Was there any way to guess this (because Razor wasn't mentioned anywhere in the question)?

Comment: The mention of `.cshtml` along with the [tag:asp.net-mvc-4] tag points at the Razor view engine. You're right, though - this might need a [tag:razor] tag, or more accurately [tag:razor-2], because Razor v1 used `<% ... %>` where v2 uses `@(...)`.

Comment: if you found a better solution, please share. thx :)

Answer (score 1):

I found a way, just enter the HEX-Code for the @-Sign

Here is a small example (in Javascrip)

```
"@".replace(/\x40/,".") // Result --> "."
```

Your code would look like this

```
var reg = /\b[A-Z0-9._%+-]+\x40(?:[A-Z0-9-]+\.)+[A-Z]{2,4}\b/i
 "ccc@er.at".match(reg) // Result => ["ccc@er.at"]
```

*=> Code Testet in Chrome 25+*